# ¿Cómo se realiza la validación de formularios en PHP para evitar ataques de inyección de código?

Tags: php, poo, security

Partiendo del clásico verificador de la existencia de un índice en una variable:

```
if (!isset($_POST['name']) && !isset($_POST['email'])) {
    //Error no existe
}
```

Luego asignando los datos del array a variables:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

¿Cuál método implementarían para evitar la inyección de código o la sanitización del mismo?

***Nota:*** No implemento ningún framework.

Comment: puedes las funciones creadas `https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php`

Comment: Un HoneyPot también es una buena forma de protegerte contra bots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Seguridad

Prevenir inyección de código SQL es un desafío complejo que requiere tiempo de investigación y conocimientos técnicos. Aquí te dejo un resumen de lo que sé basado en mi experiencia.

1. **Filtra entradas**: Primero, verifica que las entradas del cliente tengan una forma consistente y tengan el tipo de dato correspondiente. Para hacer esto en PHP en tu caso, podemos usar [`gettype`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php). Un ejemplo práctico es este

```php
$entradaCliente = $_POST["dato"];
if (gettype($entradaCliente) != "integer") { exit("..."); }
```

Esto lo que hace es verificar el tipo de la entrada del cliente, en este caso comprobamos que el tipo de dato sea un número (*integer*), pero puedes modificarlo según tus necesidades.

2. **Validación con RegExp**: Otra forma efectiva efectiva es usar expresiones regulares. En PHP, puedes usar la función [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), aquí tienes un ejemplo práctico.

```php
$entradaCliente = $_POST["dato"];
if (preg_match('/(\(\s*DROP\s+\s*TABLE)/i', $entradaCliente)) {
    exit("...");
}
```

Esto lo que hará es buscar `DROP TABLE` en la entrada del cliente, pero puedes ajustarlo o añadir más expresiones regulares, si estás iniciando en las expresiones regulares, puedes ver [esta herramienta](https://regexr.com/) para construir, entender y probar expresiones regulares.

3. **Codificación de caracteres**: Si bien puede pasar que ya protegiste tu app contra los dos puntos anteriores, todavía es importante codificar caracteres para prevenir ataques **Cross-Site-Scripting** (XSS).

En mis propias palabras

> Un ataque XSS es un tipo de ataque informático en el que el atacante inserta código JavaScript en el navegador de clientes legítimos. Esto puede suceder cuando se extrae información, previamente insertada por otros usuarios, de una base de datos, puede pasar por ejemplo en *POSTS* de foros si no se tienen las precauciones necesarias.

En PHP, puedes usar la función `htmlentities` para codificar caracteres HTML, abajo tienes un ejemplo práctico.

```php
$texo = "Hola <mundo>";
$codificado = htmlentities($texto);

print $codificado; // Hola &#x3C;mundo&#x3E;
```

4. **Prevención específica ante ataques XSS**: Prevenir ataques XSS es crucial, porque si tu app trabaja con sesiones, pasa que cuando se abre una sesión se guarda una ID de sesión en el navegador del cliente, si un atacante logra comprometer esa ID de sesión mediante un ataque de inyección XSS, podría suplantar la identidad del cliente e incluso hacer operaciones no autorizadas. Porque esa ID de sesión se envía como un encabezado al servidor en cada solicitud a este.

Para abordar esto, yo uso esta expresión regular

```js
/\<script[\s\S]*?\>[\s\S]*?\<\/script[\s\S]*?\>/ig
```

Esto lo que hace es buscar cualquier contenido en etiquetas `<script>` (incluso con parámetros y contenido) en un texto, el enfoque en PHP es usar [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) para usar esta expresión regular y poder reemplazar cualquier coincidencia en un texto. Aquí tienes un ejemplo

```php
$texto = $_POST["dato"];
$regex = "/\<script[\s\S]*?\>[\s\S]*?\<\/script[\s\S]*?\>/ig";
$replaced = preg_replace($regex, "", $texto);
```

A pesar de esto, cabe recalcar que **ningún sistema es TOTALMENTE seguro**, pero tienes que aplicar **auditorías de seguridad regulares** para poder abordar vulnerabilidades en tu aplicación y poder aplicar un parche antes que un atacante explote esa vulnerabilidad, pero en sí, en conjunto con todas estas técnicas, estrías proporcionando una capa de seguridad intermedia a tu aplicación, te recomiendo investigar para entrar *in-depth* y poder abordar más vulnerabilidades conocidas.

Incluso cabe mencionar que este no es el único ataque del que te debes de proteger. Hay muchos más ataques comunes que pueden intentar usar en contra de tu aplicación, esta lista incluye

- **Ataques DDoS y DoS**: Consisten en enviar una cantidad masiva de solicitudes al servidor con la finalidad de saturarlo y volverlo inaccesible para usuarios legítimos. Para abordar esto es necesario usar servicios especializados como Azure DDoS Protection, Google Cloud Armor o CloudFlare.
- **Ataques de Ingeniería Social**: Consiste en algunos casos suplantar la identidad de una organización o empresa, o incluso engañar y manipular psicológicamente a las personas para que revelen sus datos confidenciales como contraseñas y tarjetas de crédito. Para abordar esto es necesario implementar un sistema de [2FA](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ww/security/business/security-101/what-is-two-factor-authentication-2fa) en tu app.
- **Phishing**: Consiste en suplantar la identidad de una empresa, o falsificar un sitio que parezca legítimo con el fin de que los usuarios que accedan a él ingresen sus contraseñas u otra información sensible, se registre en las base de datos del atacante y este finalmente acceda a la cuenta del usuario legítimo. Para abordar esto, también es importante implementar el *2FA o (Autenticación de dos factores)*  como te mencioné anteriormente.
- **Ataques de fuerza bruta**: Consisten en enviar peticiones progresivamente al servidor tratando de adivinar la contraseña de un usuario, es decir tratando cada combinación de letras, número y caracteres especiales. Para abordar esto, también es importante usar el *2FA*, pero es especialmente destacable usar contraseñas fuertes, ya que los ataques de fuerza bruta requieren mucho tiempo, y si la contraseña es lo suficientemente fuerte, el atacante puede demorar muchos años en poder descifrarla totalmente.

Recuerda que la ciberseguridad es un campo complejo y en evolución y cambios constantes, por lo que lo más recomendable es mantenerse actualizados sobre las últimas medidas y estándares de seguridad.

Un buen ejemplo de esto, sin salirnos mucho de PHP, es el algoritmo [`md5`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), que tiene su implementación en PHP y que hace muchos años se creía seguro, ya que no se puede revertir, pero hoy en día, se sabe que no lo es, por eso es importante mantenerse actualizados. Una de las principales razones por las que `md5` no es seguro es porque siempre genera el mismo *hash* para una misma cadena, si bien, es *"irreversible"* hasta cierto punto, el problema surge cuando se descubrió que dos cadenas diferentes podían dar el mismo *hash*, basado en los estándares actuales, se usa [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) para codificar contraseñas, ya que es un algoritmo considerado confiable y que ha demostrado un rendimiento eficiente y respuestas positivas ante ataques de fuerza bruta. Para usar este algoritmo en PHP, puedes usar la función [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Si quieres leer más acerca de MD5, puedes leer [el siguiente artículo](https://www.avast.com/es-es/c-md5-hashing-algorithm).